# VBA Range.End(xlDown) stops at last visible row

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing a simple VBA script in Microsoft Excel which iterates a list of cars and a list of information about when the cars were refueled to provide an overview of how many kilometers each car is driving each month.

I make use of the `Range.End` property to calculate the number of rows with data and then loop through the indicies.

```vb
Set Data = Worksheets("Tankninger") ' Danish for refuellings
NumRows = Data.Range("A1", Data.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
For x = 1 To NumRows
    ' Process data
Next
```

Everything seemed to be working fine, however I found that if someone applied a filter to e.g. the sheet with refuelling data - e.g. only showing data related to car A, then `NumRows` would be assigned the index of the last visible row.

Example: if the refuling sheet contains 100 records and the records related car A are located on row 50-60, then `NumRows` would be assigned the value 60 - resulting in my script ignoring the last 40 records.

Is there a way to make the `Range.End` property ignore any filter applied to sheet, or will I have to change the implementation to use a while-loop instead?

Comment: That's the same way it works in the UI and you can't change it. If there aren't gaps in your data, you could use `worksheetfunction.counta` to count the  data rows or, if it's a Table, use that specifically.

Comment: Use this to remove any filters: `If Data.FilterMode Then Data.ShowAllData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the `for-loop` with a `while-loop`. This allowed me to access every cell regardless of any filtering applied to the sheets.

```vb
Set Data = Worksheets("Tankninger") ' Danish for refuellings
r = 2
    
While Not IsEmpty(Cars.Cells(r, 1).value)
    ' Process data
Wend
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is add the following in your code to remove filters before you find the last row with data.

```
  'Remove all filters
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

     On Error Resume Next
     ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```